# Design of a DC motor controller

Tags: circuit-analysis, motor, power-electronics, pwm, dc-motor

I want to design a control system to a DC motor using descrite component and not IC component. At the aim is to control the speed of that motor, but at the first time I want to design the inner current loop, to control the armature current of the motor.

The characteristics of the motor are:

- Armature resistance ----------> Ra=1 ohm.
- Armature inductance ----------> La=0.5H.
- EMF constante ---------------->Ke=0.01.
- Inertia----------------------->J=0.01.

I have designed a PI controller for the current loop based on what described in a book entitled: "Electric Motor Control DC, AC, and BLDC Motors by Sang-Hoon Kim".

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

**Based on that I have calculated the values of the PI controller and I have proposed the circuit below:**

[image]

V4 in the circuit is a sawtooth generator with f=500Hz, and based on that the values of R1,R2 and C1 are calculated using the formulas given in the mentionned reference (Equations 2.37 and 2.38).

**The transient simulation results of the circuit, are given below:**

[image]

**The graphs are for the feedback voltage, Verror, and duty cycle voltage (PWM generator)**
When we look to the voltage feedback, we see that it is around 2.5 volts, beside that, the error voltage is swinging between 0 and 5 volts, which makes the PWM instable

**My questions are:**

- The DC motor is usually modeled as an inductor in series with a resistor and a battery. Is it possible to use a buck converter configuration to control the armature current of a DC motor ? if so why do we use a low side drive?
- In my simulation circuit, why the PWM module is not stable even though I have calculated the PI components using the method described in the given reference?